# Will IIS always use virtual directory over a real directory?

Tags: iis

If I setup a virtual folder under a website, but there is also a real folder with the same name then can I trust that IIS will always use the virtual path rather than the real path?

Comment: Yes. Did you try typing for example D:\AFolder into your web browser to check? IIS only publishes what you tell it to

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, obviously no one is going to get to anything on my site by typing a file path. I mean if someone types http://www.example.com/foo in the address bar, then will IIS always take them to wherever the virtual folder is pointed to rather than the actual folder called foo. Because if there is no virtual folder then I know it WILL take them to the actual folder called foo (provided it exists and the security configuration allows). I have tried this and it took me to the virtual folder, but I just wanted confirmation that this is deterministic.

Comment: To further explain why I'm interested in this scenario, I am updating a website to use a virtual folder but I fear it's possible that someone else may come along and deploy the website and add back the real directory and I don't want to risk the application going to the wrong place.

Comment: By default the 'root' of IIS is set to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` (it doesn't have to be) and yes if there is a folder called _test_ created in this subfolder here it functions just like an explicitly created virtual folder. When I went and manually created a virtual folder called _test_ afterwards pointing somewhere else it replaced the definition in IIS. I guess the lesson is: don't create folders in `wwwroot` unless you are planning to configure and use them as a website.